# Restore osticket just from database

Tags: php, mysql, osticket

I have an osticket v1.15.2 instance installed in my server. After being attacked all the files were lost. I have a backup of the file ost-config.php
The database is intact.
Is it possible to restore the service just with the database and the ost-config file?
I ve already tried to upload to the server the osticket v1.15.2 files (new install) and then copy the backup of he ost-config file, but when i try to access i just get error 500.